# Oracle Original Export Database Version Support

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, expdp, oracle-export-dump

I am trying to Export a pluggable 12c Oracle database on Windows Server 2012R2. I usually use `expdp` instead of `exp`. The first trial gave me an `EXP-00058 Password Verify Function for ORA_STIG_PROFILE profile does not exist`, so I went to the file specified [here](http://www.oradba.ch/2013/07/oracle-12c-new-password-verify-function/) and created the 11G verify function. The first error didn't show up but it gave another error: `EXP-00062 invalid source statements for an object type` and for the life of me I can't tell what object this is. The question is: should I drop the whole thing since original export doesn't support 12c or is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: [It's desupported for general use](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-901CBBE0-65FB-439E-942D-F2038C18BCD2.htm#SUTIL3634); not entirely relevant but why are you trying to use it? Showing the full command you used and the output/log you got might be helpful.

Comment: the command is `exp system/pass@mypdb full=y file=D:\dumps\mydump.dmp log=D:\dumps\mydump.log` and I needed it because the DBA at my clients' site was not there to do the impdp and I don't have access to the database server to put the dump in a directory so i figured that if i put it on a client and run an original export/import it would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you need the full export - does it still complain with individual schema exports?